# Protecting process.env in nodejs when contains secrets

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

In order to avoid having secrets hard-coded into the code, I've used the standard approach of using dotenv to load an .env file when run locally, or have secrets injected into process.env in production.

However ... that got me thinking about malicious packages or stacktraces revealing the contents of process.env. And so exposing all the secrets. Given process.env is where everyone seems to store secret values, is there a risk of someone simply extracting process.env?

Is there a need to instead put the values somewhere else not so obvious? Like run over process.env, delete the values within it, and instead set up individual variables like MY_SECRET. Instead of process.env.MY_SECRET. I don't read any examples of this being recommended or done so I'd assume not (rolling my own, and all that!) but I wonder how exposed process.env is otherwise.

Comment: wdym by "exposed", if an attacker can run random code on your machine, well process.env is the least of your worries....

Comment: @Anunay True ... ! I guess while that is the obvious place to look for secrets, it would be a lazy attacker who simply stopped there. "process.env is empty? Ok, I give up then".  Just working through my list of worries ... :)

Comment: Variable contents and environment will not be revealed in a stack trace.

Comment: and to reiterate @Anunay's comment, you're right that the process environment is probably one of the first things an attacker might dump but once they can execute code they are only a few steps aways from getting at the rest of your data anyway.